# If a used car buyer backs out of buying a car do I have to return the deposit even if i didn't explicitly say it is "nonrefundable"?

Tags: united-states, utah

I have a person who said they were going to buy a car from me on craigslist. Then 3 days later he backed out. He is now threatening to sue me since I won't give him his $500 deposit back. His only argument is that I never explicitly said it was nonrefundable. Does he have any legal ground? Any recommendations?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify why I am not returning it. I normally would out of kindness but the car is a bus that I rent out on Airbnb. I had to cancel all the reservations and lost out on a couple of hundred dollars with just that. Plus the only reason I asked for it was that I had a hard offer from someone later that day. I was just trying to be nice but In retrospect, I should have sold it out from under him.

Comment: If you didn't say explicitly non-refundable, then it is expected to be refundable. Why are you being obnoxious over a deposit when you still have the car to sell?

Comment: What state is this in?

Comment: The information you added in the edit fits the *principles of equity* I addressed in item 2 of my answer (at the end).

Comment: @DavidSiegel, I am in Utah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### He may be entitled to (part) of the deposit or he may owe you more money

When you and he agreed you both entered a legally binding contract - you are obliged to sell the vehicle to him, he is obliged to buy the vehicle from you.

The deposit is merely the first instalment of the payment for the vehicle with the balance being due on delivery. They are not refundable by default.

He now wants to repudiate the contract and you have several options:

1. you can refuse his repudiation and require him to complete the contract within a reasonable time. He probably won’t do this so when he doesn’t we move on to one of the other options. In essence, this is simply a warning shot that if he doesn’t complete the contract you will move on to item 2.
2. you can accept the repudiation and sue for damages, these would include your lost rent, pro-rata of registration, insurance etc. from the time you would have sold to the time you do sell, any additional advertising, any difference in the price you ultimately get if it is lower than his offer etc.
3. you can accept the repudiation in return for keeping the deposit in lieu of the actual damages. This in makes the deposit a liquidated damages amount and it must follow all the same rules, basically it must be a genuine pre-estimate of the damage you would suffer and not be so high that it amounts to a penalty.
4. You can accept the repudiation and, as a gesture of goodwill, return some or all of the deposit.

Comment: You can not force someone to buy your car.

Comment: @Putvi you can require someone to fulfil their obligations under a contract - if they don’t you can sue for damages. In some cases (not for a car I agree) you can get an order for specific performance

Comment: Yeah if you are owed something in the contract.

Comment: @Putvi the contract was to buy the car at a specified price. The seller would be entitrled to any damages (losses) incurred because the buyer did not complete the contract. If the seller winds up better off, there are no damages.

Answer (score -1):

> If a used car buyer backs out of buying a car do I have to return the
>   deposit even if i didn't explicitly say it is “nonrefundable”?

Yes, that is very likely. With the little information you provide, it seems that the desisting buyer would be entitled to the refund for the very reason he stated.

One of the cornerstones of *contract law* is that a contract or agreement be entered *willfully* and ***knowingly***. The latter item appears to be missing here, at least with respect to the desisting buyer. It is very possible that the desisting buyer would not have made the deposit had he known that it was non-refundable.

It is noteworthy that your question does not really contain sufficient detail of the conditions of the agreement (preferably the exact wording) and who formulated them. Thus, it is impossible to ascertain the parties' intent and hence each one's rights.

Your statement that "*I never explicitly said it was nonrefundable*" suggests that the party who formulated the condition(s) is you. If that is the case, you created an ambiguity which now entitles the buyer to apply the doctrine of [*contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem), and therewith to the reimbursement.

That being said, you might be entitled to keep the money if you are able to prove that:

1. the policy of nonrefundability of
   deposits is so commonplace --in similar contexts-- that there was no
   need to make it explicit in your matter; or
2. during three-day period you declined other bids which
   would have been more profitable to you and now those bidders are no longer interested, whence *principles of
   equity* entitle you to the minimum between the deposit and the *irreversibly lost income* (see also the [*Restatement
   (Second) of Contracts*](https://www.nylitigationfirm.com/files/restat.pdf) at § 272 and 377).

Comment: It's not based on profit as said in item 2. It's based on whether he didn't fulfill an obligation. Nothing is being interpreted as far as contra pfroferentem is concerned.

Comment: @Putvi A failure to fulfill the obligation (assuming it is cognizable as such) may lead to restitution if that failure caused the OP to miss other opportunities of sale. Absent contractual specificity in this regard, that restitution is likely to be determined on the basis of the best --or perhaps the average-- alternative (if any) which the OP had to decline for the purpose of honoring the contract.

Comment: I meant that he doesn't need to show he missed an opportunity.

Comment: I am with you on the fact that the buyer didn't come through.

Comment: In what sense has the buyer not willingly and knowingly agreed to buy the vehicle? The refund-ability or otherwise of the deposit is a matter of contract interpretation, not contract formation. There is definitely a contract here, the fact that one or the other party has misunderstood a term of it does not invalidate it.

Comment: @DaleM You are not reading the complete paragraph. The very next sentence in that paragraph clearly shows I am referring to the non-refundability issue, not to the intent to buy/sell the vehicle. The contract was formed at the time (1) the buyer made the deposit, or (2) one of the parties accepted the other party's condition(s). It is unclear from the OP's question how exactly --(1) or (2)-- the contract was formed. Regardless, buyer's awareness of the non-refundability would very likely have precluded the formation of the contract.

Comment: @IñakiViggers with all due respect that is, to use the colloquium, bullshit. The buyer may have incorrectly believed the deposit would be refundable but being wrong about what you think you are contracting for does not invalidate the contract.

Comment: @IñakiViggers willfully and knowingly entering a contract requires that you understand that you are making a legal commitment - it does not require that you know every detail of what you are committing to, being ignorant of the consequences of breaching your contract does not mean you did not willfully and knowingly enter it.

Comment: @IñakiViggers precise details of payment terms are not material - a deposit is simply a payment made before receiving the goods or services. It may be refundable or (more likely) not, however, the contract is still binding even if the parties are in dispute about that.

Comment: Incidentally, “knowingly” does not mean having complete knowledge of your rights and obligations. It means having the intention that your agreement will be legally binding - transferring ownership of a car for money between non-relatives has that intention. There are plenty of binding contracts where one or both parties are in ignorance of their full rights and obligations- for example, contracts where a price is not agreed can be legally binding.

Comment: @DaleM It is odd to insist that non-refundability is "not" material. Also, you seem to ignore the notion of *rescission of contract*, a notion which can be discarded *only upon* reading the interactions between the parties (in part because it might reveal the the reason why --and the circumstances under which-- the prospective buyer backed out).

Comment: On plain reading the buyer has rescinded the contract i.e. they are in breach. Why should their breach require the return of the deposit?

Comment: The Restatement (Second) of Contracts is available [here](https://www.fbcoverup.com/docs/library/1981-Restatement-Second-of-Contracts-1981.pdf), now that the law firm of the link in this answer removed that resource and posted some useless "overview of contract law" instead.

Answer (score -3):

> > The Office of Consumer Affairs and the Motor Vehicle Dealer Board say don't make a deposit if:
> >
> > 1. You don't have the dealer's promises and assurances in writing.
> > 2. You are unsure and might change your mind about the purchase.
> > 3. Or you plan to shop at other dealerships.

http://www.nbc12.com/story/17346464/deposit-refund-question/

Legally, he shouldn't have given you a deposit until he knew he would buy the car, but whether you have to give it back would be up to a judge to determine if you acted fraudulently if he did sue. Based on the question it does not sound like you had the intent to mislead him.

Examples of misleading the buyer could include, saying the down payment would be specifically put towards the price of buying the car. If the money is earmarked for one thing and you don't deliver you are wrong. If the money was for holding the car for him or finding the car, that may not be the case.

You are supposed to have a contract that establishes this before money is exchanged.
https://patch.com/georgia/gwinnett/car-dealer-wont-refund-deposit-0

As Nij said in the comments though, morally it is wrong since you have the car and can still sell it.

Comment: One link is for VA, one is for GA. Both concern auto dealers.-- the law may differ for those not in the business, I haven't cheeked yet. The law may well differ by state. If the seller passed up possible sales, there may be damage to the seller. I have not downvoted at this time.

Comment: He didn't say what state he is in, but its not a law specifically for dealers.

Comment: Why downvote this lol?